# MongoDB - Prevent unauthorized user from opening console

Tags: mongodb

Trying to set up authorization in my development cluster, I couldn't prevent users from opening a console to my mongods.

I have enabled authorization in the config file:

```
secutiry:
  authorization: enabled
```

And have created an admin user with the userAdminAnyDatabase role.

Yet, when connecting unauthorized to this server from another machine, I can enter the console.

I do get permission error when trying to issue commands, but I would like to know if there's any way of preventing the console from opening - getting the permission error earlier.

Comment: Can you post the command you are using to connect unauthorized to the the other machine?

Comment: The command is simple: mongo ip_address:port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to access your MongoDB deployment from applications running on the same server you can use the [`bind_ip` configuration option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) to control the network interface(s) that MongoDB processes listen to. By default this should already be set to '127.0.0.1' (localhost) in packaged versions of MongoDB 2.6+.

If you want to have the server listening to a more public network interface (eg. local LAN) and want to prevent remote connections entirely, you can limit source IP access via your firewall configuration.

The [Network Security Tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-network/) in the MongoDB manual include examples that should be useful as a starting point:

- [Configure Linux iptables Firewall for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/)
- [Configure Windows netsh Firewall for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-windows-netsh-firewall/)

If users/applications might authenticate from those remote IPs, you can't prevent them from opening a console connection (with no permissions). This is similar to how other services (sshd, apache, etc) work with authentication: step 1 is to establish a connection and step 2 authenticates.

For more information on MongoDB best practices, please refer to the [Security](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/) section in the manual.